# some values changed to 0 when inserting data in yugabyte

Tags: yugabytedb

yugabyte version 2.7.1.1

This is createing table sql:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE IF NOT EXISTS xxl_job_info_id_seq;

-- Table Definition
CREATE TABLE "public"."xxl_job_info" (
    "id" int4 NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('xxl_job_info_id_seq'::regclass),
    "job_group" int4 NOT NULL,
    "job_desc" varchar NOT NULL,
    "add_time" timestamp,
    "update_time" timestamp,
    "author" varchar,
    "alarm_email" varchar,
    "schedule_type" varchar NOT NULL,
    "schedule_conf" varchar,
    "misfire_strategy" varchar NOT NULL,
    "executor_route_strategy" varchar,
    "executor_handler" varchar,
    "executor_param" varchar,
    "executor_block_strategy" varchar,
    "executor_timeout" int4 NOT NULL,
    "executor_fail_retry_count" int4 NOT NULL,
    "glue_type" varchar NOT NULL,
    "glue_source" text,
    "glue_remark" varchar,
    "glue_updatetime" timestamp,
    "child_jobid" varchar,
    "trigger_status" int2 NOT NULL,
    "trigger_last_time" int8 NOT NULL,
    "trigger_next_time" int8 NOT NULL
);
```

Here is insert sql :

```
INSERT INTO xxl_job_info (
        job_group,
        job_desc,
        add_time,
        update_time,
        author,
        alarm_email,
        schedule_type,
        schedule_conf,
        misfire_strategy,
        executor_route_strategy,
        executor_handler,
        executor_param,
        executor_block_strategy,
        executor_timeout,
        executor_fail_retry_count,
        glue_type,
        glue_source,
        glue_remark,
        glue_updatetime,
        child_jobid,
        trigger_status,
        trigger_last_time,
        trigger_next_time 
)
VALUES
        (
                3,
                'task description',
                now(),
                now(),
                'lyn',
                '',
                'NONE',
                '',
                'FIRE_ONCE_NOW',
                'ROUND',
                'testJob',
                'executorParam',
                'SERIAL_EXECUTION',
                5,
                5,
                'BEAN',
                '',
                '',
                now(),
                '',
                1,
                666,
                777
        );
```

but result in db is wrong:
[image]

And when I use the update sql to modify the values, it works.

I don't see any error in creating process:

[image]

I test some other way:
When I create another table(with different table name) using above creating tabel sql, inserting works well.
But it works wrong when I delete xxl_job_info, then recreate it with same name.

Maybe there is some dirty data in db, how could I find it ?

Comment: 2.7.x is a preview branch, and not in the stable branch. And a quite old preview branch. Can you upgrade to latest preview branch or to another stable branch and try again? See explanation: https://docs.yugabyte.com/preview/releases/ 

Meaning upgrade to at least 2.8.x or 2.15.x and try again?